# Storing the PCT from proc gchart in a table

Tags: sas

I am using proc chart on a discrete variable.
I am curious how to store just the percentage value (pct) from the output into a table ?

I tried the gout option (gout=test1) below but it stores the whole graph as an image, 
I dont want that. I just want the pct values.

proc gchart data= Native5 gout=test1;
hbar RBMI/discrete;
run;

Answer (score 1):

Well, since the GOUT option was intended to output graphics, it would be a surprise if it did anything else.  Just for the sake of interest, what version of SAS are you using?  In 9.2 the GOUT option appears to be deprecated.  Also, PROC GCHART is subsumed into PROC SGPANEL.

Is there a particular reason you want the relative frequencies from GCHART as opposed to TABULATE or FREQ?

Comment: Thanks Dennis, Proc Freq does it. I dont know why I used proc gchart...too much lemonade...thanks for your reply, this takes care the problem. I am using SAS 9.3.

Comment: GCHART and SGPANEL are not related, and are not 'subsumed'; they have nothing whatsoever to do with each other beyond being graphics routines.  GCHART is similar to the newer SGPLOT, but there are reasons to use one or the other.

Comment: @ Joe, Thanks for the info.  I stopped using SAS/GRAPH years ago in favor of R.  I suppose I ought to look at it again, but what I saw in the online documentation still looks horribly clunky.

Comment: @Dennis It's just about as clunky as ggplot2 ;)  They both have advantages, as someone who's learned both pretty well, I think ODS graphics (SGPLOT etc.) is easier to use for most things, but R is more flexible for very specific needs often.  `GTL` (the underlayer to ODS Graphics) feels a lot like grammar-of-graphics, to some extent, though it's certainly not as direct; it's probably the right place for an R programmer to be looking.